# Advanced video gallery plugin needed

Tags: plugins, gallery

OK doing a website for a client who has a multi-level video gallery.  All the video gallery plugins I found (even paid ones) don't function the way we need it to.  I thought of rolling my own solution but it would probably take too long.

The gallery must:

- Be able to support videos in sub-folders
- Allow users to navigate these sub-folders using a menu system
- Show a player, then below that, show thumbnails of the other videos in the current folder
- Allow the user to search for videos
- Play the next video in the current folder once the current video is done playing (optional)

Does such a plug-in exist? If not, I might do my own.

Comment: The media library isn’t organized in folders. You can add taxonomies or post meta data to individual files to group those.

Answer (score 1):

rarely are plugins precise o our needs.  Though something to look into is a PHP class or library for this.  Just because you are using WordPress doesn't mean you can't use other methods and include them on a custom template page or template part.